# Sonar-runner fails due to missing cxx-language plugin, although installed

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am very new to Sonar and in the process of setting up my first server/project.

Environment:

- OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 / amd64 / 6.1
- App Server: Tomcat/7.0.40I, deployed the Sonar WAR file (3.5.1).
- DB: MySQL 5.6.11

(relevant) Plugins:

- Sonar C++ Community Plugin (0.2)

The plugin is visible under General Settings --> Sonar C++ Community Plugin

sonar-project.properties

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=test:pmc
sonar.projectName=PMC
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.language=c++

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=c:/SVN/Development/test/PMC/trunk/AppServer,c:/SVN/Development/test/PMC/trunk/PmcShared,c:/SVN/Development/test/PMC/trunk/WebServer,c:/SVN/Development/test/PMC/trunk/Tools

# Optional path to the CppCheck program required to activate some CppCheck rules
sonar.cpp.cppcheck.path=C:/Program Files (x86)/Cppcheck/cppcheck.exe

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

The thing I do not understand is that it cannot find a plugin that supports the 'cxx' language:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\sonar-projects\PMC>sonar-runner
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\sonar-runner-2.2.1
Sonar Runner 2.2.1
Java 1.7.0_21 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Windows Server 2008 R2 6.1 amd64
INFO: Runner configuration file: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\sonar-runner-2.2.1\conf\sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\sonar-projects\PMC\sonar-project.properties
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\sonar-projects\PMC\.sonar
INFO: Sonar Server 3.5.1
15:20:54.231 INFO  - Load batch settings
15:20:54.794 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\Administrator\.sonar\cache
15:20:54.797 INFO  - Install plugins
15:20:55.742 INFO  - -------------  Executing Project Scan
15:20:56.482 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
15:20:56.487 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
15:20:56.493 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
15:20:56.771 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
15:20:59.229 INFO  - -------------  Inspecting PMC
15:20:59.229 INFO  - Load module settings
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 6.162s
Final Memory: 13M/221M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: You must install a plugin that supports the language 'cxx'
ERROR:
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Sonar Runner with the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run Sonar Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I do have the Sonar C++ Community Plugin installed so I guess I am missing the obvious...could someone please help me getting started?

Answer (score 1):

It seems I made a mistake in the configuration file. I re-created it and now the job runs! This issue is closed and the configurations above will work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error with the C# plugin:
*ERROR: Caused by: You must install a plugin that supports the language 'cs '*
Please remark the 'cs '
After long time I spotted the extra ' ' after 'cs'. When removing the extra space in the configuration file it worked. It seems like sonar-runner don't use "trim".

Answer (score 0):

For new users, if you still getting this error (SonarQube 4+) start the server, go to the 'Settings' ( top right ) then search for 'Update center' there you add missing modules , next restart Server. it should works
Source: [Link from official project website](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Update+Center)

Answer (score 0):

To find the string required to activate any given SonarQube language plugin, go to "Settings" -> "System" -> "Update Center". For each plugin, the short name will be in square brackets to the right of the human-readable name.

```
C / C++ / Objective-C [cpp]
```

In this example, "cpp" is the name to use in the sonar.language property in your sonar-project.properties.